# is it possible to write a generic method to select date from a datepicker calender in selenium

Tags: java, selenium

Let's suppose I have a date-picker calendar when I click on that a calendar popup will show up in which I need to select year then month then date. But I need a generic method so that whenever I click on that calendar when the calendar popup shows up. If I call a method that would select the date for me from the calendar. Is it possible to write a generic method to select a date from a date-picker calendar in selenium by just passing the desired date? I am doing it separately by selecting year then month then date like that. I have tried several methods as well.

```
SimpleDateFormat format = new SimpleDateFormat("dd-mm-yyyy");
try {
    selectDate(format.parse(ConfigurationManager.getBundle().getString("dates.holiday")));
} catch (ParseException e) {
    e.printStackTrace();
}

public void selectDate(Date date) {
}
```

Comment: Yes it can be possible. if you have same datepicker throughout your application then you can create one common method which takes date as parameter and do the selection. But if you want to use the same for other application then its not possible because there are so many types of  datepicker control available.

Comment: yes i have same date picker throughout the application. Please share the code for makemytrip datepickers FROM DATE and TO DATE.

Comment: https://www.makemytrip.com/hotels/     CheckIntime And chechout time having same datepicker...can u please write a generic code for them.

Comment: you just have to know the format of date, then simply you can create new date and send it trough sendKeys() to the input of date picker.

Comment: SO is not code writing service. please implement the concept by your self if you stuck somewhere then post your specific query with sufficient details. thanks

Comment: Thanks NarendraR.

Comment: public static void main(String[] args) {  
     SimpleDateFormat formatter = new SimpleDateFormat("dd-MM-yyyy");  
     try {  
         Date date = formatter.parse("01-04-2018");  
         System.out.println("Date is: "+date);  
     } catch (ParseException e) {e.printStackTrace();}  
 }

Comment: public Date selectDate(Date date) {
  
 WebDriver driver = new ChromeDriver();
 driver.findElement(By.xpath(".//img[@ng-click='open1()']")).sendKeys("date");
  
  return date;
 }

Comment: using these two code but still not selecting the desired date ??

Comment: You can't just sendKeys the date to a control there. You will have to click a field to open the calendar control and then click the desired date.

Comment: But select desired date there would be 3 steps like first select year then month then date.....i tried selecting the text using Robot class then parse a date and then sendkeys the date to the textfields.                                                    SimpleDateFormat format = new SimpleDateFormat("dd-mmmmm-yyyy");
   try {
   selectDate(format.parse("01-april-2018"));
   } catch (ParseException e) {
   e.printStackTrace();
   }

Comment: public void selectDate(Date date) throws Throwable {
  Robot robot = new Robot();
  CommonStep.click("date.form.leave");
  robot.keyPress(KeyEvent.VK_CONTROL);
  robot.keyPress(KeyEvent.VK_A);
  // CTRL+A is now pressed
  robot.keyRelease(KeyEvent.VK_A);
  robot.keyRelease(KeyEvent.VK_CONTROL);
   CommonStep.sendKeys(date, "date.form.leave");  ///getting error in this line
 }